# Row-wise min() of matrix with column vector

Tags: eigen

I have a m x n matrix `a` and m-element column vector `v`. I want to compute `b` such that `b(i, j) == min(v(i), a(i, j))`. How do I express this in eigen 3.3?

`a.colwise().min(v)` is not allowed because `CwiseBinaryOp` doesn't have a `min()` member function, unlike `ArrayBase`. Likewise, `operator*()` is allowed, but not `min()`.

Is there a better way than turning `v` into a matrix by replicating its elements horizontally?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I can accomplish this using `array()`, `rowwise()` and `replicate()`. Particularly:

```
MatrixXd a(3,2);
VectorXd v(3);
a << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6;
v << 3, 4, 5;
cout << a.array().min(v.rowwise().replicate(2).array()) << endl;
```